# src is used instead of target for bundling package

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, maven-bundle-plugin

When I run command "mvn package" on my project, resource files like persistence.xml, persistence.xml.dev, persistence.xml.qa etc..from src/main/resources/META-INF are packed in the bundle. I need help to make mvn-bundle-plugin to look at target folder instead of src folder because my target folder will have only one resource file persistence.xml. My pom mave-bundle-plugin is below

```
<plugin>
                      <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                      <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                      <extensions>true</extensions>
                      <executions>
                          <execution>
                              <id>bundle</id>
                              <phase>package</phase>
                              <goals>
                                  <goal>bundle</goal>
                              </goals>
                          </execution>
                      </executions>
                      <configuration>
                          <instructions>
                              <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                              <Bundle-Classpath>.</Bundle-Classpath>
                              <Meta-Persistence>META-INF/persistence.xml</Meta-Persistence>
                              <Embed-Dependency>
                                  my-project-api
                              </Embed-Dependency>
                              <Export-Package></Export-Package>
                              <Import-Package>
                                  javax.ws.rs;version="[2.0,3)",
                                  javax.ws.rs.core;version="[2.0,3)",
                                  *</Import-Package>
                         </instructions>
                      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What is your issue exactly? The persistence.xml file is not in the packaged jar file?

Comment: @Balaza Zsoldos. Issue is that the build plugin packs the output osgi bundle jar, with resources from project src folder instead of using resources from project target folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Link explains how to include resources in the final bundle under topic "Instructions -> Include Resource".
http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html

Following the documentation, I added Included-Resource tag in instructions in pom xml as below and it worked i.e. the plugin packed the resource file from target folder.

```
<instructions>
   <Include-Resource>
         META-INF/persistence.properties=target/classes/META-INF/persistence.properties
   </Include-Resource>
   <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
   <Bundle-Classpath>.</Bundle-Classpath>
   <Meta-Persistence>META-INF/persistence.xml</Meta-Persistence>
   <Embed-Dependency>
           my-project-api
    </Embed-Dependency>
    <Export-Package></Export-Package>
    <Import-Package>
          javax.ws.rs;version="[2.0,3)",
          javax.ws.rs.core;version="[2.0,3)",
     *</Import-Package>
</instructions>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default maven looks for the resources in the src/main/resources directory. It has nothing to do with maven-bundle-plugin. To configure resource handling in a different way, see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html

Comment: I found a maven-bundle-plugin documentation link which explains how to include resources in the target bundle. http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html

Comment: Balazs. Thanks for helping me out.